# Name for matrices with at least one positive vector in image

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am looking at matrices $M$ (**e:** not necessarily square) with the property that there is a vector $x$ such that $Mx$ has only strictly positive entries. I am wondering whether this property has a standard name, so that I may look up more about it. (In particular, I am interested an efficient way to compute whether a matrix has this property.)

Comment: A closely related [property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix)